# Class Help: "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Tags: python, class

I am attempting to create a Pawn class for a chess game, but I get the error "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" in the "can_move" function's first if statement, even though I define the colour as the input in the initialise function? Any ideas?

```
class Pawn(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, colour):
        #store the pawns coords
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        #store the colour of the piece
        self.colour = colour
        #store if it moved yet or not
        self.moved = False
        self.print_value = self.colour+"P"
    def can_move(newx, newy):
        #func to check if piece can move along those coords
        if self.colour == "W":
            pieces = game_tracker.live_white
        elif self.colour == "B":
            pieces = game_tracker.live_black
```

Comment: pass self to can_move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add self as an argument, representing the current instance of the class. Also indent.

```
class Pawn(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, colour):
        #store the pawns coords
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        #store the colour of the piece
        self.colour = colour
        #store if it moved yet or not
        self.moved = False
        self.print_value = self.colour+"P"

    def can_move(self, newx, newy):
        #func to check if piece can move along those coords
        if self.colour == "W":
            pieces = game_tracker.live_white
        elif self.colour == "B":
            pieces = game_tracker.live_black
```

Comment: Ah, it would appear I done derped, shoulda noticed the self! (Also it is indented properly just pasted it in wrong). Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Instance methods need `self` as **first** argument

```
def can_move(self, newx, newy):
```

Otherwise the method does not know which instance it is operating on